# Join and delete lines

Tags: python

NOTE: The solution needs to be something I can embed in python.

I have a file with 800,000+ lines. The lines are grouped. The beginning of each group of rows starts with "IMAGE" followed by one row that starts with "HISTO" and then at least one, but usually multiple, rows that start with "FRAG".

I need to:
1. Delete/discard any row that starts with "HISTO".
2. For each "FRAG" line I need to join it with the previous "IMAGE" row. 
Here is an example.

```
IMAGE ...data1...  
HISTO usually numbers 0 0 1 1 0 1 0  
FRAG ...data1...  
FRAG ...data2...  
IMAGE ...data2...  
HISTO usually numbers 0 0 1 1 0 1 0   
FRAG ...data1...  
FRAG ...data2...  
FRAG ...data3...  
FRAG ...data4...
```

The result needs to look like this:

```
IMAGE ...data1... FRAG ...data1...  
IMAGE ...data1... FRAG ...data2...  
IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data1...  
IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data2...  
IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data3...  
IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data4...
```

It is possible to have many FRAG lines before it starts over with an IMAGE line.

This is based on a previous question but now I need to use python for some consistency. 
Here is the code I was using that works.

```
> sed 's/>//' Input.txt|awk '/^IMAGE/{a=$0;next;} /^FRAG/{print ">"a,$0}'
```

Credit to AwkMan for the previous solution.

Comment: String slicing, splitting are the things you should look for

Comment: Do the lines actually start with `>` or is that just an editing artifact?

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?

Comment: That is just editing. The solution needs to be python. The line provided at the bottom works perfectly but I need to now do it in python so that I can add it to some other lines of code.

Comment: @ Wayne I have been looking but I did not know where to begin with this. It looks like string slicing, splitting is where I should start?

Answer (score 1):

#### Python solution

```
with open('Input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('>IMAGE'):
            img = line
            continue
        if line.startswith('>HIST'):
            continue
        print('%s %s' % (img, line.lstrip('>')))
```

This produces:

```
>IMAGE ...data1... FRAG ...data1...
>IMAGE ...data1... FRAG ...data2...
>IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data1...
>IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data2...
>IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data3...
>IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data4...
```

#### Awk solution

Try:

```
awk '/^>IMAGE/{img=$0;next} /^>HISTO/{next} {print img,substr($0,2)}' Input.txt
```

#### Example

With this as the input file:

```
$ cat Input.txt 
>IMAGE ...data1...
>HISTO usually numbers 0 0 1 1 0 1 0
>FRAG ...data1...
>FRAG ...data2...
>IMAGE ...data2...
>HISTO usually numbers 0 0 1 1 0 1 0
>FRAG ...data1...
>FRAG ...data2...
>FRAG ...data3...
>FRAG ...data4...
```

Our code produces:

```
$ awk '/^>IMAGE/{img=$0;next} /^>HISTO/{next} {print img,substr($0,2)}' Input.txt
>IMAGE ...data1... FRAG ...data1...
>IMAGE ...data1... FRAG ...data2...
>IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data1...
>IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data2...
>IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data3...
>IMAGE ...data2... FRAG ...data4...
```

#### How it works

Awk implicitly reads through a file line by line.  We save the IMAGE line in the variable `img` and print out FRAG lines as they occur.

In more detail:

- `/^>IMAGE/{img=$0;next}`

  For any line that begins with `>IMAGE`, we save the line in the variable `img` and then skip the rest of the commands and jump to start over on the `next` line.
- `/^>HISTO/{next}`

  For any line that begins with `>HISTO`, we skip the rest of the commands and jump to start over on the `next` line.
- `print img,substr($0,2)`

  For all other lines, we print `img` followed by the current line minus its first character (which is `>` in the sample input).

Comment: John thanks, but per the question, I need a python solution.

Comment: @ChrisNull I should have read more carefully.  Answer updated with python solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
with open('in.txt', 'r') as fin, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('HISTO'): 
            continue
        elif line.startswith('IMAGE'):
            prefix = line.strip()
        elif line.startswith('FRAG'):
            fout.write(prefix + ' ' + line)
```

Consider also that when you have an already working line command, like "John1024" awk command, you can execute it with a subprocess:

```
import subprocess
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    subprocess.run(["awk", "/^IMAGE/{img=$0;next} /^HISTO/{next} {print img,substr($0,1)}", "input.txt"], stdout=fout)
```